# Github GraphQL query "Not Found" in Swift

Tags: swift, github, graphql

I am writing the following code to write a simple GraphQL Query to ask current user's login name but I am getting a 404 for this request. I followed the instructions from [here](https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/forming-calls/#authenticating-with-graphql). Code here is actually another StackOverflow from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45205474/88898). Could someone help me debug this. This is the first time I am trying to write GraphQL queries in Swift.

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport
let headers = ["content-type": "application/json",
"Authorization": "Bearer Valid-Github-Personal-Access-Token"]

let parameters = [ "query" : "query { viewer { login } }"] as [String : Any]
let postData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://api.github.com/graphql/")! as URL, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
request.httpBody = postData as Data

let session = URLSession.shared
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
  if (error != nil) {
    print(error)
  } else {
    let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
    print(httpResponse)
  }
})

dataTask.resume()

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Answer (score 0):

@felix, did you get the `bearer token` that you need to authenticate in the API? On your code, I see a hardcoded string `"Bearer Valid-Github-Personal-Access-Token"`. If you are actually sending this instead of a real token, it might explain a `404`.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: yeah I got the valid token, I tried changing the token to invalid and I got 401. So token seems ok but even with a valid token, I get 404. I feel its hitting the rest v3 api.

Comment: Oh, I see. But I still believe that it's an auth problem. A lot of APIs return `404` on these cases, instead of `403`. The `/graphql` endpoint it's the v4.

Comment: I updated the token and verified that its working on curl but still throwing 404 on playgrounds :(

Comment: So your token is correct, but there is probably something wrong with your code and the way you are doing the request. I don't know Swift to help on this part :/

Comment: I figured out the problem, I have to change the url from https://api.github.com/graphql/ to https://api.github.com/graphql

Answer (score 0):

Github GraphQL endpoint is `https://api.github.com/graphql` and I had `https://api.github.com/graphql/`